# Download Github public assets from CLI and Dockerfile

Tags: github, curl, dockerfile, wget, github-api

I'm trying to download the networks models of a Neural Network project used to detect NSFW images. The packed models are available in the assets section of a release at this URL: https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases

I would like to create a DOCKERFILE which download these assets when built. I started using the ADD command, but the files didn't get downloaded entirely (only few kB over the 120 MB of some files). So, I tried in my Linux CLI using wget and curl... But nothing worked as expected. For example the command :

```
curl -OJL https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases/download/v0/classifier_model.onnx
```

Starts the download but only download an HTML file instead of the actual ONNX file... It seems Github is doing some kind of redirection and I don't know how I can handle it with curl/wget and finally with the ADD command of a DOCKERFILE ?

Answer (score 1):

I did visit

```
https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases/download/v0/classifier_model.onnx
```

in my browser and I did get login page, so apparently it is not publicly available. That would explain why you did get small HTML file (file with login form).

> Github is doing some kind of redirection and I don't know how I can
> handle it with(...)wget

You need to provide authentication data, I do not know how it is exactly done in this case, but I suspect they might use one of popular methods: basic authentication (see `wget` options `--http-user=`*user* and `--http-password=`*pass*) or cookies based solution (see `wget` options `--load-cookies` *file* and `--save-cookies` *file* and `--keep-session-cookies`).

Mentonied options are described in [`wget` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html), which you might access by click link or doing `man wget` in terminal.